# PHP, AJAX and Java

Tags: java, php, ajax

I have a search engine which is implemented in Java. It's very complicated. I want to use a dynamic interface for the client so I guess I should go with AJAX. I absolutely don't know NOTHING about PHP, nor AJAX and this is my first web project but I have to do it ASAP and I'm seeking to learn how to do it as fast as possible. I want my page to send the query to the Java engine, and after processing the Java code should return the result to the page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And the programming question is???

Comment: It seems he is asking how to write a UI to interface with the search engine.

Comment: "I'm seeking to learn how to do it as fast as possible" I thought it was clear (as it is for many users). Yes, Ascalonian got it right.

Comment: All the provided answers are good. I personally liked the GWT very much but it seems that because of some other problems I'm going back to .Net and Silverlight. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: right choice. in a situation where time is the main constraint one should stick with something he knows best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT ([Google Web Toolkit](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox)) is probably the fastest way for a non-UI Java guy to build a complex, ajax-enabled, dynamic UI.

Comment: I liked it very much. I think in my situation it is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you are already familiar with Java, why don't you use Java Server Pages (JSP) to build the web project?  [Here is a guide](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html) to getting up and running.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that. As a matter of fact I'm a .Net developer but since Java is very close to C#, I adapted perfectly with Java in no time but I don't know that much about Java libraries. So does JSP support creating dynamic web pages? I need to implement a web page that supports sending and receiving data and creating content based on that data dynamically.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what JSP is for.  Take a look at the example application in the guide I sent you.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look more into it. I'll set your answer as THE answer, as soon as I found out if it's what I'm looking for (which I think it is ;) )

Comment: JSP is very old, too basic and takes too much work for most projects. And it supports no AJAX out of the box.