# Silverlight - Send/Receive Data at runtime with JAVA

Tags: c#, java, .net, silverlight

Yesterday I asked about what technology should I use to create dynamic web content here:

[PHP, AJAX and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571308/php-ajax-and-java)

The suggested methods were JSP, JQuery, etc. But I thought maybe because I'm a .Net developer and I don't have any experience in web development but I have experience in WPF and C#, maybe I should go with Silverlight but the main problem here would be how can I communicate with the core part of my system which is implemented in Java?

So the main question would be: **What is the best [and easiest to learn] method to send a piece of data to the Java part, get the result and use it in silverlight? A tutorial or simple example would be nice.**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Java Web Services as stated. Use WCF to invoke the Java WS by adding a Service Reference in Visual Studio by its url, then use the proxy classes generated automatically (located in Reference.cs) to invoke the WS. This is easy but remember SilverLight WS invocations are always asynchronous, so you must cath the OnCompleted event to get the results of the invocation. WS are slow but if the machines are in the same LAN, invocation could take a few milliseconds.

I think pipes are not your solution as SilverLight executes in a Sandbox and have many restrictions on what you can do.

Comment: Thanks. Both Silverlight and Java parts are on the same system/machine. I'll try it out and as soon as I get the result I'll get back to you. Thank you again.

Comment: I used the Java Web Service and used it. Perfect. THANK you very very much. Here's how I got it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on many factors, however a relatively easy approach would be to use Java Web Services. On the .NET side, WSDL will be picked up and transformed into proxy class by WSDL.exe from the Windows SDK. If, however, these two systems are on the same server (and intend on staying this way), you may decide to use [pipes](http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.com/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html).

Comment: Thanks. What about the performance? It is very important that I use the fastest possible way. This is an interface for a search engine...

Comment: Most of the time will be consumed by the message travelling over HTTP anyway. SOAP request parsing is nothing comparing to this. If you're still concerned, do a little pilot app with a predefined request, and measure its TPS.