# Calling a Java Web service from silverlight throws an exception

Tags: c#, java, .net, silverlight

After my previous question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project), I found the solution (well, part of it).

Here's the code for Java part:

```
@WebService
```

public class MyWebService 
{
    @WebMethod 
    public String myMethod()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

```
@WebMethod
public int Add(@WebParam(name="a") int a,
               @WebParam(name="b") int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    String address = "http://127.0.0.1:8023/_WebServiceDemo";
    Endpoint.publish(address, new MyWebService());
    System.out.println("Listening: " + address);
}
```

}

And Here is the Silverlight part:

```
private void SearchResultList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyWebServiceClient proxy = new MyWebServiceClient();
        proxy.AddCompleted += proxy_AddCompleted;
        proxy.AddAsync(2, 3);
    }

    void proxy_AddCompleted(object sender, AddCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

But when I run this, e.Result throws an exception.
What am I missing/ How should I solve it?

Note that this code runs perfectly in C# Console application (when it's not async). But when I run the async code, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException when trying to access the Java Webservice from Silverlight.

There is nothing basically wrong with your code, and it should also work with async calls in C# Console App.

The main problem is that Silverlight (as a browser plugin) enforces some security restrictions that prevent a Silverlight Application to talk to another server than the one loaded from (defined by server name and port) without further configuration. This behaviour can be configured as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (also search for "silverlight cross-domain calls" or "silverlight cross domain policy").

This restrictions (normally) do not apply to desktop or console applications so they'll work fine with the same web service.

To make your code work you need to host the Silverlight Application inside the same "project" / website than your webservice (so I suppose, the self-hosting webservice won't work and you need to switch to Java web project where the webservice is to be hosted). As the Silverlight Application basically consists of an enclosing HTML file plus the referenced binaries, you can host it on any server, e.g. Apache Tomcat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are completely right. After a little investigation with the exception I found out that the InnerException was from CommunicationException which you mentioned. I found out that I have to create a clientaccesspolicy.xml file and put it in the root folder of the application. I copied it anywhere I thought of, but still no chance!

Comment: The policy file must be placed at the call target, which is in your case the web service hosting site. As mentioned in the follow-up posting, this does not seem to be possible with self-hosted web services.

Comment: I've read some places that it's possible. I think I should place it at the root folder of the Java server (which I don't know where it is, since it's not IIS and apache and I don't know which server the Eclipse uses) - More in the other post