# Java - localhost root folder?

Tags: java, .net, silverlight, eclipse, web-services

after lots of investigations for calling a web service from silverlight:
[Calling a Java Web service from silverlight throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604037/calling-a-java-web-service-from-silverlight-throws-an-exception)

I found out that I should I have to create a clientaccesspolicy.xml file and put it in the root folder of the application. I copied it in the root folder of my ASPX (web page) but it didn't help. I'm guessing the root folder should be the root folder of the server for my Java service. I have apache server on my Win7 x64 system but after stopping it the Java still worked so I'm guessing that the server for Eclipse IDE is different from Apache.

So the main question here is: **Where is the root folder of Java Eclipse server? Where should I put that xml file?**

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't possible to give you an accurate answer because there isn't one canned way of doing things in Java. Describe your Java project structure (does it have a WebContent directory) and the target application server (and it's version). When you say "Apache" are you referring to Tomcat or the Apache HTTP server that often sits in front of it?

Comment: Get any process list viewer, find running tomcat, look at it's working directory. If I remember right, Eclipse AppServers were created right in the root of C:\, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a self-hosted Java webservice with Endpoint.publish(String) then I think it is not possible to add further files for delivery, e.g. a crossdomain.xml

Instead you need to switch from a self-hosted webservice to a server-hosted webservice as described [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) (the tutorial is using Netbeans, but a similar approach should be possible with Eclipse, too, even if it might be slightly easier to use Netbeans for this example). As Tomcat is used as a server, it is also possible to deliver the corresponding Silverlight project files as well, in which case you do not need a crossdomain.xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know you've read my previous post but I don't know if you know that I have a ready to use project and it is not a web project. The main post is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project) That's where it all started. But in the tutorial it is said to create a new project. What should I do? I need to get this project ready ASAP! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that your question was a follow-up. Maybe there is a (complex) solution to have Endpoint.publish() also deliver a crossdomain.xml manually as described here: [link]http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-se-endpoints-and (but haven't tested that myself).

Comment: Oh GOD! Seriously you saved my life this time :D The article you posted what just IT! What I wanted. Just copied the class in that article, changed the port of that class to mine and it was ready to go. Note: You should change the **implements Provider** to **implements Provider<DataSource>**

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. And thanks for your helpful note.