# Java - Rich logging in web services

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jax-ws

I have a simple web service like this:

```
@WebService
public class MyWebService 
{
    @WebMethod
    public String ProcessQuery(@WebParam(name="query") String q)
    {
    // Logging here: User IP, etc.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
    String address = "http://127.0.0.1:8023/_WebServiceDemo";
    Endpoint.publish(address, new MyWebService());
    new DocumentServer();
    System.out.println("Listening: " + address);
    }
}
```

I want to add a logging method for my service to extract information. I've heard about NCSA format and Log4J but I don't know how to use them in the service. I want to log user's ip and other info. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Edit: I should note that the main part of my question is how can I retrieve some data such as user's IP, client, etc. in the web method.

Comment: Check out SLF4J and Logback for logging.  Both are super easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `WebServiceContext` to your class, so you can get the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
@WebService
public class MyWebService 
{
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @WebMethod
    public String ProcessQuery(@WebParam(name="query") String q)
    {
        MessageContext messageContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) messageContext.get(SOAPMessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);

        // now you can get anything you want from the request
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added these to my service (I changed **wsContext** to **context** I assumed that's what you meant) but when I run it the **request** would be null. What is missing? I should mention that I run the request from a silverlight app. And for the logging part, is Log4J arlight? I think I'm gonna go with it.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was typo... I guess the request is null, since you publish it using Endpoint.publish and not using the servlet container. Basically it's not a very good way, since it doesn't provide you a very good Http server. Are you plan to continue this way or move to a real server, like Tomcat/Jetty/Jboss?

Comment: Anyway, if you are not going to move to a servlet container, try to investigate the message context, what properties does it have?

Comment: Regarding Log4j, it's one of the best and most commonly used logging frameworks.

Comment: Thanks. It has some problems but after logs of struggling [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project) I decided to go with this method. It had some problems for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605998/java-localhost-root-folder) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604037/calling-a-java-web-service-from-silverlight-throws-an-exception) If there was a way to easily convert my project to a web project I guest it would be better to use it but the current code runs fine.

Comment: Well, if you are writing a real application, you won't have choice, but convert it to a web application running on a real server. If it's a homework, the build-in JDK6 Http server is fine. Anyway see this guide: http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/03/09/running-jax-ws-with-tomcat/

Comment: Thanks. It is more than a real software. It is a very big project. Shoudl I use this guide to convert my app to a web app? Sorry I'm new to Java world :D

Comment: You must put it on a real server. May be not today, but a bit later you'll need some security, load balancing and the other features the web server provides. Tomcat is a neat choice, but once you convert your application to a web application, it won't be too difficult to switch from Tomcat to another server, if you need it later. So basically yes, follow the guide :)