# Simple hello world webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, myeclipse

I have myeclipse 8.6.1 i want to build a simple helloworld webservice which i am unable to. in the myeclipse browser that appears when i have made the webservice it gives this path

```
http://homepc:8088/HelloWorld/
```

i append a ?wsdl at the end and nothing happens

i want to know the following things

1. how to make a wsdl for a java class?
2. where to keep it in the directory so it appears in the ?wsdl and thus the webservice is discoverable
3. What else is required to build an up and running webservice in myeclipse?

i have followed this http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_overview/

but it desnt tell how to proceed further it just tells you how to start in different ways

thanks

Comment: See if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project/5598853#5598853

Comment: you should try `http://localhost:8088/HelloWorld` instead of `homepc`. Also, make sure that the port number is correct (not 8080?).

Comment: thanks rakaszeru, surprising to know apache is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all this researching i found out that myeclipse is not so good for web development atleast in java, so i shifted to netbeans, used version 6.9.1 and there you can just make a webservice in a few clicks, it takes care of the directories and deployment.