# How to generate a web service from a WSDL

Tags: java, linux, wsdl, wsimport

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I checked the stackoverflow history/questions and it does not quite answer what I am trying to do. I have a WSDL. I want to generate a web service for that WSDL. I know that I have to manually write something, but that's the part I need help.

I have a WSDL. I save it in /home/username/java/ws/wsdl/test.wsdl. I also have an xsd at /home/username/java/ws/wsdl/test.xsd used by the aforementioned WSDL.

I generate the server stubs for this like so:

```
[/home/username/java/ws/wsdl/] $ wsimport -p com.uptimeservice.ws -d build/classes -s src wsdl/test.wsdl
```

Now, I need an implementor. I create one like so under /home/username/java/ws/src/WsImpl.java:

```
package com.uptimeservice;  

import javax.jws.WebService;  

import com.uptimeservice.ws.*;  

@WebService(name = "UptimeService",
        targetNamespace = "test",  
    serviceName = "UptimeService",  
    portName = "UptimeServiceSOAP",  
    endpointInterface = "com.uptimeservice.ws.UptimeService",
    wsdlLocation = "/home/username/java/ws/wsdl/test.wsdl")  
public class WsImpl implements UptimeService {  

@Override
public UptimeResponseType uptimeRequest(UptimeRequestType msg) {  
    UptimeResponseType resp = null;
        return resp;  
    }  
}
```

I compile it like so:
[/home/username/java/ws/src/] $ javac -classpath /home/username/java/ws/build/classes/:. com/uptimeservice/WsImpl.java

Then when I try to deploy the service, like so:
/home/username/java/ws/src/] $  java -classpath /home/username/java/ws/build/classes/:. com/uptimeservice/WsImpl

I get the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

My guess is that this is something very trivial, but I am not a Java person.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the environment you use e.g. apache cxf, axis2 etc...? it is also recommended to use ide like eclipse or netbeans, as I can see that you are writing on some notepad and compiling it manually. SB

Comment: I am using a Linux environment, and everything is just command line. I am trying to NOT use eclipse etc. I am using xemacs for my development.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a webservice will be installed on a java web server, such as Tomcat, Jboss, Jetty, Websphere, in a war file.

You are trying to run it manually, as a standalone application, and all standalone applications need a main function called `main`, just as C or C#, for example.

So, how are you actually going to deploy this, on a webserver or as a standalone application?

If you do it as a standalone application then you will need an embedded http server, btw.

Comment: I understand that I will need a web server--no worries there. If you look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project/5598853#5598853), you will see that getting a webservice from the implementation (and not the contract) is easier, and does not seem to need more than the Java libraries in WebService and WebMethod, both of which are  embedded in my code. What am I missing?

Comment: In WsImpl there is no main.  The wsimport command will generate the code, then you need to call it from an application, either deployed on a webserver or from a standalone application. When you try to do java ... WsImpl the java command is looking for a main, not finding it, so throwing an error.

Comment: OK. That part about the main I got already. What do I have in the main that will deploy the web service? When I add main(), it just exits the program, and the webservice is not deployed. To check if the webservice was deployed, I added a sleep in the main, but that did not help either. I am not sure I follow.

Comment: You may want to look at something like this: http://tech-eureka.blogspot.com/2009/10/jax-ws-inside-jetty.html