# how to do selfhosting web service in java application

Tags: java, web-services, self-hosting

I have a `Java Application`. I use `Netbeans 7.4` IDE. I want to host some `web service methods` within this application so that other clients can get data provided by this application using web service.
I don't want to host this web servis on any web server, i want to host this only within the application itself `like WCF selfhosting in .NET`.
I have been developing C# applications and i have knowladge about WCF but i am just a starter of Java world. Is it possible to host web service endpoints within the application itself like happens in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

The answer accourding to my needs is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project)

I see that I just need to add new java class and add xml annoitions like @WebService and @WebMethod to make the class a web service. Then i just need to add following lines to publish this service:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address = "http://127.0.0.1:8023/_WebServiceDemo";
        Endpoint.publish(address, new MyWebService());
        System.out.println("Listening: " + address);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 6, a web server is provided with the jre (com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer). Some frameworks can take advantage of this (restlet for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you mean by "self-hosting". The easiest way to do this is to use an embedded Jetty server in your application. This is typically frowned upon though as it ties up one port for each web service, and if you're going to have more than a handful, it's quickly going to become difficult to manage, as opposed to simply hosting all your webservices in the same container. But if it's just for a small private project, that nobody else is going to use, running as an embedded Jetty or Tomcat will be fine. Be aware that there will be cloud services that may be difficult to use, but again if this is not a concern, go ahead.